# cannot evaluate the item metadata

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

When attempting to load a project within my solution, I am getting the following message:

[image]

This is how it is triggered:

[image]

The [sfproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079411/how-to-use-msbuild-on-the-sfproj) source is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.5.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>725d4b15-19f6-4b58-9e54-9e911657b4e4</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectVersion>1.5</ProjectVersion>
    <MinToolsVersion>1.5</MinToolsVersion>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="ApplicationPackageRoot\ApplicationManifest.xml" />
    <None Include="ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml" />
    <None Include="ApplicationParameters\Local.1Node.xml" />
    <None Include="ApplicationParameters\Local.5Node.xml" />
    <None Include="PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml" />
    <None Include="PublishProfiles\Local.1Node.xml" />
    <None Include="PublishProfiles\Local.5Node.xml" />
    <None Include="Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app.config" />
    <Content Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Web\Web.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationProjectTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Service Fabric Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationProject.targets</ApplicationProjectTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(ApplicationProjectTargetsPath)" Condition="Exists('$(ApplicationProjectTargetsPath)')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.5.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets')" />
</Project>
```

**What am I doing wrong? How can I get this project to load correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/03/17/visual-studio-2017-and-service-fabric-tools/): have you installed the Azure Service Fabric Runtime and SDK?